# Contribution of a single value in a Division of Sums

Tags: mathematical-statistics, percentage, ratio, sum

I need to isolate contribution of a single entity in a Division of Sums as shown below. For example, find the contribution of variable `a` in the following: (a <sub>1</sub> + b <sub>1</sub> + c <sub>1</sub>) / (a <sub>2</sub> + b <sub>2</sub> + c <sub>2</sub>)

Example with numbers:

| Stock | $ Earnings | $$ Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 10 | 100 |
| MSFT | 25 | 50 |
| AMZN | 5 | 50 |

```
Profit Margin = (10+25+5)/(100+50+50) = 20%
```

I need to break down this 20% into contributions by AAPL only for example.

Comment: How does the need for a numerical value of "contribution" arise? What's your definition of "contribution" in this instance? You could conceive of the overall ratio (the mediant of the individual ratios) as a weighted average of individual ratios, but ... are you seeking that weight in particular, or something else?